# How do I peek at the top of a std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<...>> without popping nor taking ownership

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

Code pasted below with some comments. I need to look at the top of a `std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<...>>` but if I call `.top()` I get a compiler error: "attempting to reference a deleted function". I know I could call pop, but I need to do some logic based on the value first to determine whether I want to pop it.

```
struct MyStruct {
    int val = 2;

    MyStruct(const int val) : val(val) {}
};

void testDeque() {
    // This block won't compile because of call to q1.top()
    std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> q1;
    q1.emplace(std::make_unique<MyStruct>(10));
    // How can I "peek" at the value at q1.top() without taking ownership of the unique_ptr?
    MyStruct* nonOwnershipPtr = DO_SOMETHING_MAGIC(q1.top());
    // At this point, the unique_ptr at t1.top() should still be there
}
```

Comment: `top()` gives you  reference and should let you do what you want. You probably have a bug in `DO_SOMETHING_MAGIC`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Not necessarily a bug in the function; just it needs to take its parameter by `const&`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
MyStruct* nonOwnershipPtr = q1.top().get();
```

Comment: Ugh. I know I tried that. But since the error is in "xmemory0" instead of telling me where my code is wrong, I probably had an error somewhere else when I did. Thanks!